# When to choose static utility and when spring component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, refactoring

We have a legacy project which uses many static utilities in that project.

Now we have to write `Junit` of this project, some refactoring will be done.
Some of static utility classes are creating problem in writing Junit of some classes.

Should we refactoring all those static utilities into Spring Component?

---

I have few points in my mind :

- When writing `Junit` it will also call static utility..  is it still considered single `Junit` or integration testing because it will test functionality of multiple public methods?
- Some Utility also uses extra dependency and as this is in separate file we cannot mock those dependencies, hence Junit fails.
- Junit of those static utilities will be written in there individual files, then why test those static utility in multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

> Should we refactoring all those static utilities into Spring Component?

1. IMHO: If currently those static utilities are not dependent on Spring, you shouldn't add extra redundant dependency.
2. You suggest refactoring to be able to write the tests for refactoring. But you don't want to refactor without tests. Do you see recursion here? )

> we cannot mock those dependencies

3. Isn't it a reason to think about better design which would allow mocking the external dependencies. Maybe it could be a part of coming refactoring?

> why test those static utility in multiple files?

You can structure the tests [one way or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589178/one-test-class-per-method). I'd sat the more important now is to define a target coverage and reach it. E.g. you can specify target coverage as: 100% classes, 70% branches, 80% lines, etc.

Good luck with tests and refactoring!